# Redshift: Alternative to filter 1st row after "row_number() partition by", with better performance

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, row-number

In this example, I try to get the datetime and product name of the 1st order from each customer.

My query looks like this:

```
select * from(
    select customerid,
           orderdatetime,
           productname,
           row_number() over (partition by customerid order by orderdatetime) rn
    from t
) where rn=1
```

In table `t`, `customerid`+`orderdatetime` can serve as the primary key, while `productname` is free text characters. There are huge number of customers, and each customer made significant number of orders.

I feel that in this query, much calculation is wasted in `order by`, because I want only the earliest (minimum). Is there really such waste? Is there alternative way to get the result, which is faster?

I'm using Amazon Redshift‎.

Comment: have you tried using "min(orderdatetime)" aggregation on grouping by customer and then doing join with "t" to get "productname"? just to compare the speeds

Comment: @mangusta, I tried that with a small portion of data. The current approach returned in 30s, while "min() with group by" returned in 77s.

Answer (score 0):

you can try by using corelated subquery, as customer id and orderdatetime is primary key
 so it may help to get better performance

```
select t.* from your_table t 
     where orderdatetime = (select min(orderdatetime) from your_table t1
                                       where t1.customerid=t.customerid
                                       )
```

Comment: Hi Zaynul, maybe I didn't state clearly.
In table t, the pair of "customerid + orderdatetime" is unique, while each customer can appear multiple times, and at each orderdatetime multiple orders could occur.

Comment: in your solution, what do you mean by 'your_table'?

Comment: @WestYang thas means the table that you used from query